# MVC Validation - Updating another field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

We are currently creating a couple of input fields which will contain a start and end datetime, one in each field. We have validation currently working so that it displays an error message if a user puts the start time after the end time (and vice verse for an end time before the start) however we have come across an interesting issue with this.

If the user, for example, puts an end time before the start time, we get an error message on the end time as expected.

[image]

However if the start date is then amended as opposed to the end date, the message remains.

[image]

Is there a way to remove/update/correct the validation message on a different field? Here's the code for the validation:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required!")]
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[Remote("IsTestPlanEndCorrect", "Analysis", AdditionalFields = "EndDate", HttpMethod = "Post", ErrorMessage = "Test Plan Start Time must be before End.")]
public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required!")]
[Display(Name = "End Date")]
[Remote("IsTestPlanEndCorrect", "Analysis", AdditionalFields = "StartDate", HttpMethod = "Post", ErrorMessage = "Test Plan End Time must be after Start.")]
public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

`IsTestPlanEndCorrect` is simply a method which returns true or false depending if the passed data passes the validation.

EDIT:
Razor code for the fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(t => t.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", placeholder = "Enter Test Plan Start"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.StartDate)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.EndDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", placeholder = "Enter Test Plan End"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.EndDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

Validation code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsTestPlanEndCorrect(DateTime EndDate, DateTime StartDate )
{
    return Json(TimeManipulation.checkDate(StartDate,EndDate));
}
```

Comment: What does your validation code `IsTestPlanEndCorrect ` does?

Comment: `Analysis` is the name of the controller which has the `IsTestPlanEndCorrect` method

Comment: Yea. Can you share the code of that ? When you udpate the start date, Is it making the async call ?

Comment: I'll update my post

Comment: and How does your razor code (For these 2 fields) looks like ?

Comment: Why don't you use MVC custom validation attributes? Ideal for situations like these. Here's a guide to start: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

Comment: Wow thanks @AmateurProgrammer, had no idea custom validation was a thing (still very new to MVC)! That's looking very promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that jquery client side validation is triggered for the element you editing (initially on `.blur()` and thereafter on `.keyup()`). Changing the value in the `StartDate` textbox does not trigger validation of the `EndDate` value, it only triggers validation of the `StartDate` value, so therefore the validation message does not disappear.

You could solve this by specifically triggering the `.keyup()` event in the 'other' textbox, for example

```
$('#StartDate').change(function() {
    $('#EndDate').trigger('keyup'); // or $('#EndDate').valid();
});
$('#EndDate').change(function() {
    $('#StartDate').trigger('keyup'); // or $('#StartDate').valid();
});
```

However using a `RemoteAttribute` to check values which are already known in the client is a waste of resources and you would be making a minimum of 2 calls to your database each time you alter the values. In addition, remote validation is client side only and you need to repeat you validation logic again in the POST method and manually add `ModelStateError`'s to protect against a malicious user.

Instead, use a custom validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` so that you get both client side and server side validation without the need to ajax calls. For a good guide on implementing your own, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). Or for a ready made solution, consider using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` and `[LessThan]` validation attributes. Note that typically you apply one or the other to one of the properties, but if you do want to apply it to both, e.g.

```
[LessThan("EndDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
[GreaterThan("StartDate")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

then you will still need to trigger the `.keyup()` events noted above to make the other message disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to / need to achieve this with `jQuery`:

```
$('#StartDate, #EndDate').change(function() {
    $('#StartDate, #EndDate').valid();
});
```

This will cause the validation to be called for ***both*** fields every time there is a change on ***either*** field. You will probably want to add some additional checks in this code, for example, if end date is empty, you probably don't want to check it just yet.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to link this to html validation at all? This solution looks ideal but I'm unsure how to link it to the actual validation message

Comment: @Novastorm Apologies, I'm being dumb. How do you mean? If you have jQuery validation on the front end (presumably you do because of remote validation), then it should be fine and do it automatically.

Comment: Ah so the validation message you see on the UI is coming from our ViewModel (which is the first chunk of code in the post). I think the remote is used to define that the validation is performed application side rather than client side (as this method is being hit when breakpoint and debugged in the code). When I say link it back to the html validation I'm referring to the message you get in the UI (poor choice of working on my part there!)

Comment: @Novastorm No worries. The validation is performed server side for the date check, but the result of that true/false is dealt with client side, and if it's not valid, then you'll see the message. 
Calling `.valid()` from `jQuery` simulates the same workflow as tabbing out naturally.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much, I'll give that a try :)